# PSQLException: ERREUR: realtion "table" doesn't exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, orm

When I run the program a PSQLExecption is thrown, I've tried to trace it but couldn't find what causes this exception.I've tried to add a schem and entity name as i read in other posts but that hasn't worked

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category" , schema = "schem")
public class Category {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
  public List<Question> questions;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CID")
  private Long categoryId;

  @Column(name = "CName", unique = true)
  private String categoryName;

  public Category() {
    questions = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public Long getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
  }

  public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
  }

  public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Category)) {
      return false;
    }
    Category category = (Category) o;
    return getCategoryName().equals(category.getCategoryName());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getCategoryName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating your table via a script or it is generated automatically?

Comment: the table is created using the entitymanager when persisting the data

Answer (score 0):

You can try these common problems that might cause that error:

- Checking the schema has the right name
- Checking the name of the table has the correct name (case sensitive)
- Checking if you save and flush the table you're creating before actually calling it